# Don't clear query parameters after clicking a link

Tags: html, angular, hyperlink

currently my file download looks like this

```
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="downloadFile()">
```

I use the `a` tag in order for the text to look and behave like a normal link.

[image]

Everything works fine, except that after pressing the link and downloading the file, the query parameters are being removed(because the routerLink is empty). Is there any workaround or another way to keep the current functionality and look, and don't remove the query parameters?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: IMO using anchor just for it's looks is overkill. Instead you could remove the `routerLink` and use CSS to style the link.

Comment: maybe you're right, I though that making the css would be a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `[routerlink]` is not mandatory. You could simply remove it and use the `<a (click)="myFunc()"></a>` as a button. This way, your link actually only performs the onClick function and leaves your location as is.

Then just style the `<a>` as a link with a css class to keep the looks of a link.

Comment: yes, but wouldn't I lose the looks of a link? It wouldn't not look like a hyperlink(color,underline etc) anymore

Comment: It is possible to do a location change and keep the query parameters, but that is more complicated than creating a css class that makes an `<a>` look like a link. My suggestion is to create a "link" class and add that to the `<a>`, `<a class="link" (click)="downloadFile()">some name</a>`